# Getting Method Not Found on Google My Business API when trying to query accounts

Tags: google-my-business-api

<sup>Organization: TDn2K

Project Name:Google My Business API

Project Id:lateral-robot-231516

Project Number: 750273937300</sup>
<sub>Consumer Key:   750273937300-6eudgbu3iku197anujoip56ssu99h4js.apps.googleusercontent.com</sub>

I am getting an access token, and refresh token, but when I query https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts, I get a `Method Not Found` response.

Comment: What HTTP method are you using and which are supported by that endpoint?

Comment: a get on https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts

Comment: Try putting your access token at the end of the URL? `?access_token=tokenHere`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but same response. I have a ticket open with google. I believe it to be a setup issue.